# Taking next steps in Vulkan, after tutorial

Tags: vulkan

I have gone through this tutorial for Vulkan: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/
Now I am trying to figure out what are the best steps to move forward with drawing multiple objects.

For simplicity, lets say I want to have a scene where I have 2 different static objects with different textures placed and 2 different dynamic ones with differend textures.
How would be a good way to setup the descriptor sets, descriptor pools, uniform buffers, vertex buffers etc?
Should I just have one for each? Or should they all share the same buffers with different offsets? Or should the static one share and the dynamic ones share? Should each object have its own descriptor set/pool? What are benefits/drawbacks from each one having its own uniform buffer for the MVP matrices and update each individually?

And would it be good to have a renderpass for the static objects and another renderpass for the dynamic ones or could they share the same?

Any clarifications are appreciated!